# Video upload compression different between via Request and FacebookDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm noticing a big difference in video compression quality when uploading a video via `FacebookDialog` versus `Request.newUploadVideoRequest` where via `FacebookDialog` the quality is worse.

Any ideas why this is happening and if there are any options to disable this compression? I really want to use `FacebookDialog` since it already provides the whole UI and sharing options.

- [Via Request.newUploadVideoRequest](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10101257541573506&l=6273630759384901571)
- [Via FacebookDialog video sample](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10101256271868006&l=6167909220042222099)

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I just filed a bug... https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/818822814853261/